# Javascript animated gradients don't show up

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gradient

I know it's pretty stupid, but I really don't know why it does not work. I'm looking to make animated gradients like here: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/BzJkQv.
I've copied exactly all the lines, but it's still white background. I've put everything in just a HTML script, here it is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>home</title>
<!--<link href="home_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
<style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    canvas {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: scale(2);
    }   
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    function Pixel(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
        var direction = Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        this.velocity = (Math.random() * 30 + 20) * 0.01 * direction;
    }
    Pixel.prototype.update = function () {
        this.hue += this.velocity;
    };
    Pixel.prototype.render = function (ctx) {
        var hue = Math.round(this.hue);
        ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 50% )";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1, 1);
    };
    function animate() {
        pixels.forEach(function (pixel) {
            pixel.update();
            pixel.render(ctx);
        });
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    var pixels = [new Pixel(0, 0), new Pixel(1, 0), new Pixel(0, 1), new Pixel(1, 1)];

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    animate();
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    <canvas width="2" height="2"></canvas>
    <!--
    <div class="login">
      <h1 id="login_title">Login</h1>
        <form method="post">
          <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
            <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Let me in.</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is exactly my current code.
Could you please help me? If you need any more information, feel free to ask! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts inside the `<script>...</script>` tag is loaded before the content. You need to wrap js logic in the **window load** event. Like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
   ...
}
```

Full code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function Pixel(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
        var direction = Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        this.velocity = (Math.random() * 30 + 20) * 0.01 * direction;
    }
    Pixel.prototype.update = function () {
        this.hue += this.velocity;
    };
    Pixel.prototype.render = function (ctx) {
        var hue = Math.round(this.hue);
        ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 50% )";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1, 1);
    };
    function animate() {
        pixels.forEach(function (pixel) {
            pixel.update();
            pixel.render(ctx);
        });
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    var pixels = [new Pixel(0, 0), new Pixel(1, 0), new Pixel(0, 1), new Pixel(1, 1)];

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    animate();
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work... :( I'll edit my question now with your code.

Comment: @MarcVana, Please check the snippet I added. It works.

Comment: @MarcVana, What errors are you getting in the console? Have you wrapped in the window load event correctly?

Comment: It seems the problem it's not in the code, it's idk where. The snippet runs here in stackoverflow, but if I copy it and paste it in my html file and run it, either in Edge or Chrome, my screen is still white. Thanks a lot for your answer, I don't think the problem is in the code anymore. You helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I have an error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (from :60738/favicon.ico:1 ) only on chrome it seems. on edge it's fine, no errors, but still white screen

Comment: I think i've found the answer, just let me 10 minutes and I'll write you back here.

Comment: Yeah, I found it. This is so stupid. With your code, now it works perfecly only if I double click on the html file in the file explorer. If I try to open it from inside the Adobe Dreamweaver or Visual Studio (with option Open in browser) it does not work. So this is a software issue, not a coding one, after you gave me the working code. Thanks a lot, you saved me!

Comment: @MarcVana, no problem. Glad to help. Visual Studio, do you mean Visual Studio Code? Strange, I never had a problem with him.

Comment: Not the Code version. Visual Studio 2019. I know it's strange.

Comment: @MarcVana, Tomorrow at my work I'll try this ide :)